# For some reason, I can not get rid of the clear button for UISearchDisplayController iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

I tried doing what a stackoverflow answer directed me to, but I seem to be not able to get this to work. The answer on stackoverflow did get some upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want it only for iOS 7, try this:

```
- (void)configureSearchBarView {
    for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews){
        if ([view conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
            [(UITextField *)view setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
        }
    }
 }
```

As you have a property for searchBar you do not need to pass any parameter to the method, so the above code should do the job. If you want the clear button never occur use `UITextFieldViewModeNever` option instead of `UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing`

Comment: undocumented API's usually create problem down the road.

Comment: which part is undocumented?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it works for iOS7 too:

```
//First add the following macro:
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

//Then access your search bar text field:
- (void)configureSearchBarView
{ 
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        for (id object in [[[self.searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews])
        {
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                [((UITextField *)object) setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (id object in [self.searchBar subviews])
        {
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                [((UITextField *)object) setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I added this code, and add this in viewDidLoad `[self configureSearchBarView];` and it didn't work sadly.

Comment: Should I add the outlet from files owner or viewcontroller?

Comment: Yes, make sure that the outlet is properly connected.